# Admin Create New Order Observer

Tags: model, event-observer

I am trying to locate the correct observer to capture the data when the admin creates a new order. I do not want this observer to be triggered when frontend orders are placed. (Only admin backend created orders)

I have tried the following but these still get triggered if a customer places an order on the frontend.

```
sales_order_place_before
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
sales_order_save_after
```

Again, what is the proper observer that will be triggered if the admin creates an order and not the frontend created orders?

Comment: Try with `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of placing your event observer code into the `<global>` node just place it inside the `<adminhtml>` node in your module's config.xml file.

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about that. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: It's so simple.

Comment: Can anyone help me here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7

Answer (score -1):

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
you can use this event for frontend order placed.

Comment: But this was not the question.

Comment: Then use this event 'adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data' and place events file into adminhtml folder.hope it will work for you.